# Arduino serial not working depending on project

Tags: arduino

Good morning everyone!

I encounter a very surprising problem with arduino serial.

Here is my program:

```
/*
//#include "SerialLogger.h"
//#include "PeriphHydro.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
    
    void setup() {
        // put your setup code here, to run once:
        Serial.begin(9600);
        delay(1000);
        
        Serial.println("hello world");
        
        
        //VERBOSE("starting");
        
        //delay(3000);
        //free_draw();
        //delay(2000);
        
    }
        
    void loop() {
        
        //VERBOSE("\n\n >>> LOOPING <<<\n");
        Serial.println("here");
        delay(500);
    }
    */

//////// Now comes the uncommented code 
       
    #include <Arduino.h>
            
    void setup() {
        // put your setup code here, to run once:
        Serial.begin(9600);
    }
        
    void loop() {
        // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
        delay(500);
        Serial.println("hello");
    }
```

As you see, everything is commented except a very simple setup() and loop(). This code inside my Draw_test.ino project displays this on the serial:

`Ơ�9DX��`

(unique, not periodical)

Sometimes it shows this:
`xf�f��f~�����`f�����f���~��f������f���fxx��W�)� `

Or this:
`Ơ�;DX��`

If I copy-paste the same code to a new blank sketch, the serial monitor displays:

hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
...

Note that in this second case, 0% program space is used. But in the first case, 3% are used. I understand that unsused files are compiled. May it interfere with Serial.println() ?

In the two cases, I am using the same board, same port, same baud rate 9600 (code and monitor).
I tried to restart Arduino, it doesn't help. IDE 2.0.4

Do you have any idea on what's going on?

I do thank you for your help,

Bests,

Francis

I tried to restart Arduino, it doesn't help.
The code only works inside another project.

Comment: When opening the serial monitor you have to select 9600 bps. You are seeing junk because you probably have the serial monitor with the wrong baudrate

Comment: You are right, I have to select the correct baud rate. But it is already 9600, same as inside the code, in the two cases

Comment: Your question is just how to send a hello world from an arduino and read it from the Arduino IDE right? First you should not import Arduino.h this is not needed. Upload just a minimal example and check what you receive in the serial port. There's even an example of that in the Arduino examples section.

Comment: It is not my question. My question is "why the serial is not working within my first sketch and is working fine within my second sketch?"

Comment: My second question is : "is it possible that commented code or unused code (unused handmade libraries) interferes with running code?" Thank you for help!

Comment: I don't know. Your first sketch is fully commented between /* and */  so it should not even compile. In the first sketch you are unnecessarily doing `#include "Arduino.h"` then in the second one you are unnecessarily doing `#include <Arduino.h>`  I don;t know why in one case ou use "" and in the other case you use <>  but importing Arduino.h is not necessary at all.

Comment: You show one sketch only. Can you post Draw_test.ino code and libraries origin as I can reproduce problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue!

Inside a constructor (file Electrovalve.cpp, which header is called inside PeriphHydro.cpp, which header file is called inside Draw_test.ino but commented), I had a call to VERBOSE(), which is a macro of SerialLogger.h using the serial function written in SerialLogger.cpp.

Here is the constructor:

```
    Electrovalve::Electrovalve(int evPin)
{
    VERBOSE("Initializing EV"); // Makes Serial to crash
    pinMode(evPin, OUTPUT);
    close();  // inside here, there is a working VERBOSE()
}
```

The solution:

```
    Electrovalve::Electrovalve(int evPin)
{
    // VERBOSE("Initializing EV"); // delete this line
    pinMode(evPin, OUTPUT);
    close();
}
```

Note that inside Electrovalve::close(), there is a working call to VERBOSE()...

```
    void Electrovalve::close()
{
    digitalWrite(EV_PIN, EV_IS_CLOSED);
    VERBOSE("EV closed"); // This works
}
```

Please note again that PeriphHydro.h and Electrovalve.h ARE NOT inside the running code. Their call ARE COMMENTED. But still it is run somehow and make Serial crashing.

**I would be glad to have any interpretation of this strange behaviour.**

PS: without #include Arduino.h, delay() and Serial.println() are considered as not declared